# SharePoint 2019 js code in CEWP and SEWP stops working

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, sharepoint

using SharePoint 2019 on-premise, client-side, Classic Site not Modern.

within a SharePoint list I have a SEWP with the following

```
<script src="/sites/xyz/29jl2020/SiteAssets/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script> 
<script src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/15/sp.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var siteUrl = 'https://somesite.com/sites/xyz/29jl2020/'; 

    function retrieveWebSite(siteUrl) {
        alert("Hello World");
        
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
        this.oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
        clientContext.load(this.oWebsite);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
            Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), 
            Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
        );
    }
    
    function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
        alert('Title: ' + this.oWebsite.get_title() + 
        ' Description: ' + this.oWebsite.get_description());
    }
    
    function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
        alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + 
        '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }

</script>
```

and using a CEWP, the following

`<input id="btnClick" onclick="retrieveWebSite();" type="button" value="add a new item"/>`

when initially created this simple function, it worked.  But when I leave the list and come back to the list, clicking the button gives no results. If I go to List's Edit Page and either go into edit of either CEWP or the SEWP and just click the ok with no changes, the code starts working again. Until I leave the list and come back to the list, it's stop working again.

I'm definitely new at coding for SharePoint.  Am I missing something in the code?  I don't want the code to be trigger onload but on the button event.

As always any help is greatly appreciated.
Thank you,
Benny

Comment: Are there any errors reported when the code cannot run?

Comment: no, it just stops working, I then just go to either the CEWP or the SEWP edit web part and click ok, and then everything works until leave the site and come back to it. I have closed IE and started again, refresh, nothing. I have another site with a lot more going on and it started there. So, I created this small sample and it just starts doing this once I leave the site and comes back to it.

Comment: I can not reproduce it.

Comment: Hi Amos_MSFT, so this is working ok for you? Do you have it in a document library or a list, or??? Also what type of site is it? I thinking maybe it might be site type dependent. I have a Team Site (Classic) and then a list page. Thank you for taking the time.

Comment: Team site,list page.